# Read Minecraft Forge configuration file from Bukkit plugin?

Tags: config, minecraft, bukkit, minecraft-forge

I am trying to read the contents of a [`forge cfg file`](http://www.minecraftforge.net/wiki/Tutorials/Configuration_files) from my bukkit plugin. I can successfully get the file, however I cannot read the values from bukkits' [`FileConfiguration`](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/configuration/file/YamlConfiguration.html) (as far as I'm aware of). Here is an example `forge cfg file` from a mod:

```
# Configuration file

####################
# player1
####################

player1 {
    I:player2=1
    I:player3=1
}


####################
# player2
####################

player2 {
    I:player1=1
    I:player3=1
    I:player4=1
 }
```

Is it possible to read these values?

Answer (score 0):

Forge uses a different format than bukkit, so the methods would not be compatible. You need to write a manual parser, copy in whatever forge uses, or use it from MCPC+ (As whatever you want is most likely targeted for an MCPC+ server (A spigot server (a kind of bukkit) mixed with forge).